# Numerical Relativity for Computer Scientists

Tags: general-relativity, resource-recommendations, computational-physics, simulations, education

What resources on numerical relativity/simulation would be suitable for a primarily theoretical computer science background [algorithms analysis, complexity theory, etc.]? Importantly, while I'm planning to take an introductory graduate general relativity class next semester, *I don't yet have background on the relevant physics* (though I do understand basic topology and differential geometry, as well as some special relativity).

As such, I'm looking for resources that are accessible to non-physicists (so ideally they would be self-contained and include just enough background to get started with simulations).

Comment: It is easy to underestimate the complexity and computational requirements of Numerical Relativity, even with all the physics and programming done for you!  I would recommend reading the following paper (The Einstein Toolkit: A Student's Guide) to find out if it is really for you:  https://arxiv.org/abs/2011.13314

Comment: I imagine someone who wrote a GR/SR simulation toolbox is probably designing it for users who are (fairly) familiar with both GR & SR, so I'd be surprised if any such tutorial exists. You may be putting the proverbial cart before the horse.

Comment: More on [res. recom. for numerical relativity](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/computational-physics+resource-recommendations+general-relativity).

Comment: My recommendation would be that you look up the textbook used in your GR course and start reading it. I think all resources for numerical GR will assume you know GR, e.g. "Numerical Relativity" by Baumgarte and Shapiro assumes knowledge of GR.